# Printing the number of different numbers in python

Tags: python, printing, numbers

I would like to ask a question please regarding printing the number of different numbers in python.

for example:
Let us say that I have the following list:

```
X = [5, 5, 5]
```

Since here we have only one number, I want to build a code that can recognize that we have only one number here so the output must be:

```
1
The number is: 5
```

Let us say that I have the following list:

```
X = [5,4,5]
```

Since here we have two numbers (5 and 4), I want to the code to recognize that we have only two numbers here so the output must be:

```
2
The numbers are: 4, 5
```

Let us say that I have the following list:

```
X = [24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26]
```

Since here we have two numbers (24 and 26), I want to the code to recognize that we have only two numbers here so the output must be:

```
2
The numbers are: 24, 26
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you tried?

Comment: Use ```set()``` on that list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try numpy.unique, and use len() on the result

Answer (score 1):

You could keep track of unique numbers with a set object:

```
X = [1,2,3,3,3]
S = set(X)
n = len(S)
print(n, S)  # 3 {1,2,3}
```

Bear in mind sets are unordered, so you would need to convert back to a list and sort them if needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can change this **list** into **set**, it will remove duplicate, then you can change it again into list.

```
list(set(X))
```

Answer (score 0):

May I ask you please if we can use set() to read the data in a specific column in pandas?
For example, I have the following the DataFrame:

```
df1= [ 0 -10 2 5 
       1 24 5 10 
       2 30 3 6 
       3 30 2 1 
       4 30 4 5 ]
```

where the first column is the index..
I tried first to isolate the second column

```
                                           [-10 
                                             24 
                                             30 
                                             30 
                                             30]
```

using the following: `x = pd.DataFrame(df1, coulmn=[0])`
Then, I transposed the column using the following `XX = x.T`
Then, I used set() function.

However, instead of obtaining
`[-10 24 30]`
I got the following `[0 1 2 3 4]`

So set() read the index instead of reading the first column

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).